# How to prevent Shell auto-logout from terminating my screen session?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

c shell

and

echo $autologout

shows 60

But I can not unset this variable since it`s read-only, error message: `set: $autologout is read-only.`

Everytime when the shell is auto logged out, my screen session also got terminated, very annoying. How to prevent this from happening? Or even better, how to disable this auto-logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround to keep the screen session alive is easy. Just start a second shell (with `control-a` `c` and start a program.

According to [this page](http://www.cnr.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/Variable_substitution.html) it is possible to set read only variables in csh and tcsh with `set -r`.   Quoting from that page:

```
 Variables may be made read-only with `set -r' (q.v.) Read-only variables may
 not be modified or unset; attempting to do so will cause an error. Once made
 read-only, a variable cannot be made writable, so `set -r' should be used 
 with caution. Environment variables cannot be made read-only.
```

Which means you can not unset or change this **in this shell**.

This seems to leave you a few options:

For starters you can check your homedir for a `.login` or a `.cshrc` If they are set in either of those two, edit the file and it will be active when you log in next.

Alternatively it can be set from `/etc/csh.cshrc` in which case it is a default for all csh users on the system. I am not sure if you can override that by setting another value in your own config files. That probably comes down to which configuration file is read first.

Thirdly you can compile your own csh. This is probably a bit over the top, but if you **need** csh then it is an option.

Lastly: If you do not need **c**ch but just a shell you could check if other shells (ksh, bash, /bin/sh) are configured with the same values. It feels like a dirty workaround (even worse than compiling your own version) so I left this as last option.

Comment: the error message `set: $autologout is read-only.`

Comment: Thanks. It`s set in /etc/csh.login, don`t see a way to unset it in my own config files, .cshrc . I ended up making screen starting a non-login shell in .screenrc config file.